# Fill missing values of one column from another column in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

I have two columns in my pandas dataframe.

I want to fill the missing values of `Credit_History` column (dtype : int64) with values of `Loan_Status` column (dtype : int64).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df.Credit_History = df.Credit_History.fillna(df.Loan_Status)
```

Or:

```
df.Credit_History = df.Credit_History.combine_first(df.Loan_Status)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Credit_History':[1,2,np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Loan_Status':[4,5,6,8]})

print (df)
   Credit_History  Loan_Status
0             1.0            4
1             2.0            5
2             NaN            6
3             NaN            8

df.Credit_History = df.Credit_History.combine_first(df.Loan_Status)
print (df)
   Credit_History  Loan_Status
0             1.0            4
1             2.0            5
2             6.0            6
3             8.0            8
```

Comment: @jazreal:After the `combine_first` operation on `Credit_History`, does `Loan_Status` column present in the new dataframe?