# Merge adjacent columns containing NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

One column has NaN and some values, the other columns also has NaN and some values. It is not possible for both columns to have values but it is possible for both columns to have NaN. Is there a way I can merge the columns together?
I've tried selecting one column and `df.fillna` with a forumla, that doesn't work.

```
quad_data['new'] = quad_data.apply(lambda x: function(x.a, x.b, const_a, const_b), axis=1)
df1 = pd.merge(df1, quad_data[['a','b','new']], left_on=['a','b'], right_on = ['a','b'], how='inner')


    new_x       new_y
0   NaN         0.997652
1   NaN         0.861592
2   0           NaN
3   0.997652    NaN
4   0.861592    NaN
5   2.673742    NaN
6   2.618845    NaN
7   NaN         0.432525
8   NaN         NaN
9   0.582576    NaN
10  0.50845     NaN
11  NaN         0.341510
12  NaN         0.351510
13  1.404787    NaN
14  2.410116    NaN
15  0.540265    NaN
16  NaN         1.404787
17  NaN         2.410116
18  NaN         0.540265
19  NaN         1.403903
20  1.448987    NaN
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill missing values of one column from another column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790183/fill-missing-values-of-one-column-from-another-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`combine_first` and `fillna` are good alternatives in general, but these alternatives work since your `NaN`s are exclusive.

**Option 1**
*`df.max`*

```
s = quad_data.max(1)
print(s)
0     0.997652
1     0.861592
2     0.000000
3     0.997652
4     0.861592
5     2.673742
6     2.618845
7     0.432525
8          NaN
9     0.582576
10    0.508450
11    0.341510
12    0.351510
13    1.404787
14    2.410116
15    0.540265
16    1.404787
17    2.410116
18    0.540265
19    1.403903
20    1.448987
dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**
*`df.sum`*

```
s = quad_data.sum(1)
print(s)
0     0.997652
1     0.861592
2     0.000000
3     0.997652
4     0.861592
5     2.673742
6     2.618845
7     0.432525
8          NaN
9     0.582576
10    0.508450
11    0.341510
12    0.351510
13    1.404787
14    2.410116
15    0.540265
16    1.404787
17    2.410116
18    0.540265
19    1.403903
20    1.448987
dtype: float64
```

---

```
quad_data['new'] = s
```

Comment: That's Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Try this .. LOL

```
df.bfill(1)['new_x']
Out[45]: 
0     0.997652
1     0.861592
2     0.000000
3     0.997652
4     0.861592
5     2.673742
6     2.618845
7     0.432525
8          NaN
9     0.582576
10    0.508450
11    0.341510
12    0.351510
13    1.404787
14    2.410116
15    0.540265
16    1.404787
17    2.410116
18    0.540265
19    1.403903
20    1.448987
Name: new_x, dtype: float64
```

Comment: `bfill` along the first axis? Quite inventive!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it is hard to think out side your guys box:)

Comment: @Wen, i think this is the most idiomatic and generic solution. ++

Answer (score 1):

You can use combine_first

```
df['new'] = df['new_x'].combine_first(df['new_y'])
```

Or simply

```
df['new'] = df['new_x'].fillna(df['new_y'])
```

You get

```
    new_x       new_y       new
0   NaN         0.997652    0.997652
1   NaN         0.861592    0.861592
2   0.000000    NaN         0.000000
3   0.997652    NaN         0.997652
4   0.861592    NaN         0.861592
5   2.673742    NaN         2.673742
6   2.618845    NaN         2.618845
7   NaN         0.432525    0.432525
8   NaN         NaN         NaN
9   0.582576    NaN         0.582576
10  0.508450    NaN         0.508450
11  NaN         0.341510    0.341510
12  NaN         0.351510    0.351510
13  1.404787    NaN         1.404787
14  2.410116    NaN         2.410116
15  0.540265    NaN         0.540265
16  NaN         1.404787    1.404787
17  NaN         2.410116    2.410116
18  NaN         0.540265    0.540265
19  NaN         1.403903    1.403903
20  1.448987    NaN         1.448987
```